# Oracle APEX 21.2.6 Interactive Grid - double-click to edit popup LOV shifts data rows over. How to prevent this?

Tags: oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I have an IG display that looks like this without clicking anything else:
[image: display before double-clicking to edit]

Only Supervisor, and Direct Supervisor are editable, and they are both Popup LOV's.

If I double-click the Supervisor data, and immediately type any letter for the Popup LOV search, the data row(s) display shifts to the left like this:
[image: display after double-clicking, and typing a letter]

It doesn't matter how wide the window is when I test this.  I've been looking for ways to prevent that shift.  Do you have any tips to resolve that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I've since learned that this is a known issue, and a bug report was logged:  https://community.oracle.com/tech/developers/discussion/4340268/apex-20-1-popup-lov-in-interactive-grid-causing-issue/p1?new=1

I've also noticed that it seems to happen from a single click plus typing to search - not necessarily from a double-click.

Finally, freezing a column or two in place in the IG display appears to prevent the visual shift of the columns.

Comment: More specifically - you have to freeze every column in the IG to the left of the column you want to be able to edit with a Popup LOV